# C# Stopping recursion

Tags: c#, recursion

So I have made a maze where '#' are walls and '.' are available coordinates to move to. I'm attempting to stop the recursion when it finds its way outside of the maze. So when either (x,y) is 12. This may be a simple fix.

This is my maze...

```
char[,] maze1 =
            // USE THIS
        { { '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#' },
        { '#', '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#' },
        { '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#' },
        { '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', '#' },
        { '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '.', '.' },
        { '#', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#' },
        { '#', '.', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#' },
        { '#', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#' },
        { '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', '#' },
        { '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#' },
        { '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', '.', '.', '#' },
        { '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#' } };
```

Here is my method...

```
private void mazeTraversal(int currentX, int currentY, char[,] maze)
    {
        /*************** ATTEMPT 1 ******************/

        // Checks if coordinates are inside the maze
        if (currentX <= 11 && currentY <= 11)
        {
            // Implement maze traversal recursive call
            //PrintOriginalMaze(maze, currentX, currentY);

            // If the coordinate is a '.' , continue(This is the base case)
            if ('.' == maze[currentX, currentY])
            {
                // Changes location to a X so you cant go back.
                maze[currentX, currentY] = 'X';

                // Implement maze traversal recursive call
                PrintOriginalMaze(maze, currentX, currentY);

                mazeTraversal(currentX, currentY + 1, maze);
                // maze[currentX, currentY] = 'X';

                mazeTraversal(currentX - 1, currentY, maze);
                //maze[currentX, currentY] = 'X';

                mazeTraversal(currentX + 1, currentY, maze);
                // maze[currentX, currentY] = 'X';

                mazeTraversal(currentX, currentY - 1, maze);
                //maze[currentX, currentY] = 'X';

            }

            if ('#' == maze[currentX, currentY])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hit a wall");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't you be outside of the maze if either x or y is 0 as well? You should display more of your code to actually display the recursion. At this point, I'm *guessing* that code belongs to `PrintOriginalMaze`. What does `mazeTraversal` do? BTW, methods should start with uppercase. And why are you using recursion instead of just a loop?

Comment: Why are we using recursion here? i mean this sounds like a one way street to stackoverflow'vile. Also why dont you just check the bounds of the array, obviously if you are over the bounds, you are goneskis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question, and you are trying to determine if the current `x` and `y` are outside the *bounds* of your maze (`array`)

You could use [`Array.GetUpperBound(Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getupperbound?view=netframework-4.8)

> Gets the index of the last element of the specified dimension in the
>   array.

```
var maxX = maze1.GetUpperBound(0);
var maxY = maze1.GetUpperBound(1);

if (currentX > maxX || currentX < 0 || currentY > maxY || currentY < 0)
  return;
```

Stopping the *recursion* is just a matter of exiting the method consistently (on some state) to *unwrap* the call, i.e using a `return` when your current `xy` is outside the *bounds*.

Answer (score 0):

You really should put a "exit" node in the labyrinth. At [4][11] I think. Then it would be a simple check if you found the exit(node).

What you have here is the age old problem of gameboards: "How do I deal with stuff just outside the playfield?" and "What do I do if I am at a border and want to check all neighbouring cells?"

For the most part, you avoided that problem. You have a "border" of walls. Putting a non-enterable border around the gameboard is one of the solutions. The other would be dealing with all those Index checks. But personally I prefer accounting for a border.